# When is every group of order $n$ nilpotent of class $\leq c$?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, finite-groups

In the paper 'Nilpotent Numbers' by Pakianathan and Shankar (http://www2.math.ou.edu/~shankar/papers/nil2.pdf), it was proven that every group of order $n$ is nilpotent if and only if $p^k\not\equiv 1\mod q$ whenever $p,q$ are distinct primes with $p^k$ and $q$ dividing $n$. I am interested in finding conditions on $n$ such that every group of order $n$ is nilpotent of class at most $c$; has there been any work on this problem already?

(At least the case of $c=1$ has been done, as these are the abelian numbers.)

Answer (score 1):

The numbers $n$ for which every group of order $n$ is nilpotent of class at most $c$ are the nilpotent numbers that are not divisible by any $(c+1)^\mathrm{th}$ power.

This is because a finite nilpotent group is the direct product of its Sylow subgroups, the class of the group is bounded by the classes of its direct factors, and a $p$-group of order $p^{c+1}$ has class at most $c$.

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-group) for the existence of $p$-groups of maximal class.

Comment: Thanks, I just realized this... except how do we know the condition is necessary? Can you find $p$-groups of order $c+1$ and class $c$ for every $c$?

Comment: @FrancisBegbie Yes, I've added a link to a reference.

Answer (score 1):

For a reference, see the following article by Müller.

> Müller, Thomas W. *An arithmetic theorem related to groups of bounded nilpotency class.* J. Algebra 300 (2006), no. 1, 10–15. [DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgebra.2005.10.013)

The solution is basically the one given by James in his answer.