# Is every group of order $136$ nilpotent?

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, sylow-theory, nilpotent-groups

> Is every group of order $136$ nilpotent?

The answer is no. Consider the group $G=\mathbb{Z}_{17}\rtimes_\phi \mathbb{Z}_8$ where $\phi: \mathbb{Z}_8 \to {\rm Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_{17})\simeq \mathbb{Z}_{16}$ is a non-trivial homomorphism (such homomorphism exists because $8$ divides $16$). If $G$ was nilpotent it would be the direct product of its Sylow subgroups, namely $G = \mathbb{Z}_{17} \times \mathbb{Z}_8$. But since $\phi$ is not trivial this can't be the case (as $G$ would be abelian).

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Yes, yours is fine. Alternatively, $D_{34}\times C_4$ would work.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Thanks. $D_n$ is nilpotent iff $n=2^k$ right?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise the reflection acts on an odd order rotation, and thus the Sylow $2$-subgroup cannot be a separate normal subgroup from the odd Sylows.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Or $D_{68} \times C_2$ or $D_{136}$.

Comment: There are fifteen groups of order 136, five of which are nilpotent.

Comment: Related: [For which $n$ is every group of order $n$ nilpotent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1690316/for-which-numbers-n-is-every-group-of-order-n-nilpotent) and [Pete Clark's](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/299/pete-l-clark) answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67407/group-of-order-15-is-abelian).

Comment: @David A. Craven About your last remark: could you say where such information can be found ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Search Google for the Magma online calculator. Then input:
n:=136;
{* IsNilpotent(SmallGroup(n,i)):i in [1..NumberOfSmallGroups(n)] *};

Comment: @David A. Craven A big thank.